# Django - 2 csrf tokens

Tags: django, csrf

I have two forms in one page and when i submit one of them, I can't submit the second form and i have an error about a CSRF Token missing, but I have the `{{% csrf token %}}` in my forms.

I'm reading the django docs, but i can't find a solution that talk about a rotation of csrf token, or generating two tokens for two different forms.

Comment: You don't need different tokens for each form. Please show the code of your view and template.

Answer (score 0):

This `{{% csrf token %}}` is wrong.

Use `{% csrf_token %}` which will render the complete hidden input or `{{csrf_token}}` which will only render the token itself.

So either:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Or, if you need it in JS for AJAX driven requests:

```
<a data-csrf="{{csrf_token}}" />
```

Comment: I know the {% csrf_token %}, i didn't check my code for the correct syntax but the idea is there. I will check for the <a> that you give, thanks :)

Comment: Well, the correct syntax is quite essential. I'm sure it will work just fine having two forms in one template both using csrf. This is nothing fancy, just stick to the Django documentation.